# pandas Iterate through Rows & Column and print it based on some condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

I have an excel file & I Processed that file for Data Analysis and Created a `Data Frame(Pandas).`
Now I Need to Get the result ,
I'm trying to get it through iterating over pandas columns and rows using `for & if` Condition But I'm not getting desired output.  
I've Taken hyphen(-) in excel file so that I can apply some conditions.

Excel File
[Input_File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqkHz.png)

```
Required Output
A -> B -> C -> E -> I
F -> G ->L
H -> J -> K 
A1 -> B1
C1 -> A1
Z -> X
Note: Saving Output in Text file in plain. No need of Graph / Visualization
```

code

```
df =  pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx')
df.fillna('-')
     
# Below code answer Z -> X
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Start_Name'] != '-':
        if row['End_Name'] != '-':
            print(row['Start_Name'] +' -> '+ row['End_Name'])

# Below code answer A -> B / F -> G / H -> J / C1 -> A1     
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Start_Name'] != '-':
        if row['Mid_Name_1'] == '-':
            if row['Mid_Name_2'] != '-':
                print(row['Start_Name'] +' -> '+ row['Mid_Name_2'])

# Below code answer B -> C /  C -> E
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Mid_Name_1'] != '-':
        if row['Mid_Name_2'] != '-':
            print(row['Mid_Name_1'] +' -> '+ row['Mid_Name_2'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup:

`Fronts` dictionary holds value/position of the sequence that stars with name/key.

`Backs` dictionary holds value/position of the sequence that ends with name/key.

`sequences` is a list to hold all combined relations.

`position_counter` stores position of last made sequence.

```
from collections import deque
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("Names_relations.csv")

fronts = dict()
backs = dict()

sequences = []
position_counter = 0
```

[Extract_all](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html#pandas-series-str-extractall). For each `row` select values that match regex-pattern

```
selector = data.apply(lambda row: row.str.extractall("([\w\d]+)"), axis=1)
```

For each `relation` from `selector` get extracted elements.

Put them to the queue.

Check if `front` of new `relation` can be attached to any previous sequence.

If so:

1. take `position` of that sequence.
2. take sequence itself as `llist2`
3. remove last duplicated element from `llist2`
4. add the sequences
5. update `sequences` with connected llists
6. update `backs` with position of the current end of the seuquence
7. and finally remove exausted ends of the previous sequence from `fronts` and `backs`

Analogous to `back in fronts.keys():`

If no already existing sequence match to new relation:

1. save that relation
2. update `fronts` and `backs` with position of that relation
3. update position counter

```
for relation in selector:
    front, back = relation[0]
    llist = deque((front, back))

    finb =  front in backs.keys()
#     binf = back in fronts.keys()

    if finb:
        position = backs[front]
        llist2 = sequences[position]
        back_llist2 = llist2.pop()
        llist = llist2 + llist
        sequences[position] = llist
        backs[llist[-1]] = position
        if front in fronts.keys():
            del fronts[front]
        if back_llist2 in backs.keys():
            del backs[back_llist2]

#     if binf:
#         position = fronts[back]
#         llist2 = sequences[position]
#         front_llist2 = llist2.popleft()
#         llist = llist + llist2
#         sequences[position] = llist
#         fronts[llist[0]] = position
#         if back in backs.keys():
#             del backs[back]
#         if front_llist2 in fronts.keys():
#             del fronts[front_llist2]

#     if not (finb or binf):
    if not finb: #(equivalent to 'else:')
        sequences.append(llist)
        fronts[front] = position_counter
        backs[back] = position_counter
        position_counter += 1

for s in sequences:
    print(' -> '.join(str(el) for el in s))
```

Outputs:

```
A -> B -> C -> E -> I
F -> G -> L
H -> J -> K
A1 -> B1
C1 -> A1
Z -> X

#if binf is active:
# A -> B -> C -> E -> I
# F -> G -> L
# H -> J -> K
# C1 -> A1 -> B1
# Z -> X
```

Name_relations.csv

```
Start_Name,Mid_Name_1,Mid_Name_2,End_Name
A,-,B,-
-,B,C,-
-,C,E,-
F,-,G,-
H,-,J,-
-,E,-,I
-,J,-,K
-,G,-,L
-,A1,-,B1
C1,-,A1,-
Z,-,-,X
```

Comment: Thank You @woblob  your answer just saved me !