# python dictionary and deque to print required output based on some condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, for-loop, deque

I have `CSV File` which contains some data Produced from Mining 
I wanted to print it as shown in required format

```
Required Format
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F
A -> B -> C -> I
X -> Y -> Z
X -> Y -> P -> Q
A -> B -> K -> L
```

*a.csv File* 
[image]

```
## code
from collections import deque
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("a.csv")

data['Start'] = data['Start'].str.replace(' ','_')
data['End'] = data['End'].str.replace(' ','_')

fronts = dict()
backs = dict()

sequences = []
position_counter = 0

selector = data.apply(lambda row: row.str.extractall("([\w+\d]+)"), axis=1)

for relation in selector:
    front, back = relation[0]
    llist = deque((front, back))
    
    finb =  front in backs.keys()
    
    if finb:
        position = backs[front]
        llist2 = sequences[position]
        back_llist2 = llist2.pop()
        llist = llist2 + llist
        sequences[position] = llist
        backs[llist[-1]] = position
        if front in fronts.keys():
            del fronts[front]
        if back_llist2 in backs.keys():
            del backs[back_llist2]

    if not finb: 
        sequences.append(llist)
        fronts[front] = position_counter
        backs[back] = position_counter
        position_counter += 1

data = []
for s in sequences:
    data.append(' -> '.join(str(el) for el in s)) 
data
```

**What I'm Getting is:**
'A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F' 
'C -> I' 
'A -> N -> A' 
'X -> Y -> Z' 
'Y -> P -> Q' 
'B -> K -> L' 
'X1 -> Y1'

Comment: @woblob I found your answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64206914/pandas-iterate-through-rows-column-and-print-it-based-on-some-condition. You have any idea How I'm I able to get required output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search the existing paths for the starting element of the new row. If found, append to the existing path or copy the path and append the new end element.

Try this code:

```
ss = '''
A B
B C
C D
D E
E F
C I
A N
N A
X Y
Y Z
Y P
P Q
B K
K L
X1 Y1
'''.strip()

lst = []
for r in ss.split('\n'):
   lst.append(r.split())

################

paths = []
for e in lst:  # each row in source data
   pnew = []  # new path
   for p in paths:
       if e[0] in p:  # if start in existing path
           if p.index(e[0]) == len(p)-1:  # if end of path
               p.append(e[1])  # add to path
           else:
               pnew.append(p[:p.index(e[0])+1]+[e[1]])  # copy path then add
           break
   else:  # loop completed, not found
      paths.append(list(e)) # create new path
   if len(pnew):  # copied path
      paths.extend(pnew) # add copied path

print('\n'.join([' => '.join(e) for e in paths]))
```

Output

```
A => B => C => D => E => F
A => B => C => I
A => N => A
X => Y => Z
X => Y => P => Q
A => B => K => L
X1 => Y1
```

The `A->N->A` and `X1->Y1` are correct based on the source data. I don't know why they would be excluded in the desired output.